# A way to retrieve all strings from .net project?

Tags: .net, string

Is there a way to list all strings (that are not embeddet in a ressource) in a .net project?
I'm particulary interested in messagebox strings etc. so I can check if everything has been translated and written correctly. All tools I have tried so far can only list ressoure strings.

Any help very appreciated.

Ah forgot to say: I'm a Windows guy running Windows and only Windows, so please tell me something that runs on windows. I don't mind a simple way without using command line tool hacking etc., but will certainly do it if really neccessary.

**Update**: It's possible to use regex expressions directly in VS search which is very handy.

> ("[^"]*")

Matches all strings. However I want to list strings with at least one space character only.

**Update2** "([^"])+:b+([^"])+" Does what I need. Hope it helps someone else.

Thanks!

Comment: Your requirement sucks big time! :P

Answer (score 7):

This should help to some extent:

Use `ildasm` to dump the IL to a file. Then run this in PowerShell:

```
cat filename.il | where { $_.Contains("ldstr") }
```

Comment: @Yuval A: 1: Requirement wasn't there when I answered. 2: grep runs on Windows. 3: This is just an idea. Not a complete solution.

Comment: So maybe there is a slightly more convenient way? ;)

Answer (score 1):

"([^"])+:b+([^"])+"  This matches all strings with at least one space character. For me this is sufficient. Feel free to modify it if you need to. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Mehrdad's idea of getting ILDASM to dump IL output to a file and searching for `ldstr` is exceptionally brilliant. I confess, it never occurred to me to use such a method.

If you need GREP solutions for Windows, my best experience has been using [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) or it's big brother - [PowerGREP](http://www.powergrep.com/).